# on Tkinter can't create multiple buttons with diffrent arguments in loop

Tags: python, button, tkinter, lambda, arguments

Im trying to make many buttons on my screen with for loop.Im using lambda for call my function with arguments.But i can't give diffrent arguments to each button.So i need to know why is this happening. Whats the solution for this. Is tkinter using same RAM cache for these buttons ? If so , i tried to give diffrent names with another list to these buttons but problem was same. Thanks for answering already..

```
from tkinter import *
def printmyvalue(value):
    print(value)
app = Tk()
test_list = []
for i in range(10):
    test_list.append(Button(app,text=str(i+1),command=lambda : printmyvalue(i)))
    test_list[i].grid(row=i)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=lambda args=i:printmyvalue(args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was so many times - so you could find it.

```
command=lambda args=i:printmyvalue(args)
```

In your version `lambda:printmyvalue(i)` doesn't copy value from `i` to function `lambda` but it keeps reference to memory used by variable `i`. So all buttons get the same reference to the same memory. When you click button then it get value from this memory but  in this memory is last value used in loop - so all buttons use last value.

Using `lambda args=i:` it creates new variable `args` in every `lamba` and it copies value from `i` to `args - so every`lambda` uses different variable with different value.